# textarea post into mysql not working

Tags: mysql, post, textarea

I have a textarea in a form that im trying to POST into a mysql database.  However, when i insert the values, i get about 5 lines in the database. 4 of them have no information or minimal information and one of the lines is how i want it.  How can i get rid of the other four lines? thanks.

EDIT:  actually none of the lines have all the right info in the right spots and i have double checked the inset statement to make sure everything lines up.

the code:

```
<form method='POST' action="index.php">
<textarea id ='answerbox' autocomplete='off' cols="80" rows="5" name='answer'></textarea>
<input type='submit' value='submit'>

<?php
    include 'connect.php';
    $date=date("Y-m-d");
    $time=time();
            $answer=['answer'];
    $user=$_SESSION['username'];
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    $put=mysql_query("INSERT INTO solutions VALUES ('','0','$date','$time','$user', '$answer')");
    ?>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be saving the value from the textarea as there is no ref to $_POST['answer'] in your code. Is the code above complete?

Comment: It should be $_POST['answer'] not ['answer']. Also, your PHP code should have a condition to add the data only if the variable in $_POST['answer'] is available. Otherwise you will be just adding unnecessary data into your table every time you load your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php
    if($_POST['answer'] != '')
    {
       include 'connect.php';
       $date=date("Y-m-d");
       $time=time();

       $answer= $_POST['answer'];
       $user=$_SESSION['username'];
       $id=$_GET['id'];
       $put=mysql_query("INSERT INTO solutions VALUES ('','0','$date','$time','$user', '$answer')");
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your textarea is named as "answer" while its ID is "answerbox".  You should be able to retrieve its value through $_POST['answer'];